# remove array that have same array in order to get the correctness of array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Problem on counting the similarity between two arrays. I want to compare two arrays. First array is student input while second one is teacher. 
For example my two arrays

First array

```
Array
(
    [0] => <mo>+</mo><mfrac><mrow>
    [1] => <mo>+</mo><mn>2</mn><mi>x</mi>
    [2] => <mo>+</mo><mn>1</mn></mrow><mrow>
    [3] => <mo>+</mo><mi>x</mi>
    [4] => <mo>+</mo><mn>2</mn></mrow></mfrac>
    [5] => <mo>+</mo><mfrac><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></mfrac>
    [6] => <mo>-</mo><mfrac><mrow>
    [7] => <mo>+</mo><mn>2</mn><mi>x</mi></mrow><mi>x</mi></mfrac>
    [8] => <mo>-</mo><mfrac><mrow>
    [9] => <mo>-</mo><mn>3</mn>
    [10] => <mo>-</mo><mn>1</mn></mrow><mi>x</mi></mfrac>
)
```

Second array

```
Array
(
    [0] => <mo>+</mo><mfrac><mrow>
    [1] => <mo>+</mo><mn>2</mn><mi>x</mi>
    [2] => <mo>+</mo><mn>1</mn></mrow><mrow>
    [3] => <mo>+</mo><mi>x</mi>
    [4] => <mo>+</mo><mn>2</mn></mrow></mfrac>
    [5] => <mo>+</mo><mfrac><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></mfrac>
    [6] => <mo>-</mo><mfrac><mrow>
    [7] => <mo>+</mo><mn>2</mn><mi>x</mi></mrow><mi>x</mi></mfrac>
    [8] => <mo>-</mo><mfrac><mrow>
    [9] => <mo>-</mo><mn>3</mn>
    [10] => <mo>-</mo><mn>1</mn></mrow><mi>x</mi></mfrac>
)
```

My current coding

```
<?php

$total = 0;
$total1 = max(count($final),count($final1));
for ($i=0; $i < count($final) ; $i++) {
    for ($j=0; $j <count($final1) ; $j++) { 
       if ($final[$i]==$final1[$j])
        {
          $total++;
          // unset($final[$i]);
        }
        else 
        {

          // echo $final[$i];
        } 
    }
unset($final[$i]);
} 
$finaltotal = ($total / $total1) * 1;
```

The output :

```
your total mark is : 0.54545454545
```

When i comment the `unset` the total marks is `1.1818181818182` due to repetition of 2x and -1. My goals is **when the answer from student match to teacher, it will remove it from that array**.

How can i do that? I have try `array_diff()` but not return the total marks.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: sorry my bad, repetition of <mo>-</mo>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you can use `array_diff` for this case, it seems simpler than you think:

```
$studentInput = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$teacherInput = ['a', 'c', 'c'];

$total = count($studentInput);
$mistake = count(array_diff($studentInput, $teacherInput));
$percentOfMistake = $mistake / $total; //0.33333333333333
$percentOfCorrect = 1 - $percentOfMistake; //0.66666666666667
```